# $wpdb DELETE SQL from root

Tags: php, sql, database, wordpress

I'm trying to delete transients from the db each day using a cron. I currently have this in a file in the root of my site:

```
<?php    
include_once("wp-load.php");
global $wpdb; 
$wpdb->show_errors(); 
$wpdb->query("DELETE FROM `".$wpdb->prefix."options` WHERE `option_name` LIKE ('_transient_%')");
$wpdb->print_error();
?>
```

It does nothing and prints out this:

WordPress database error: []
DELETE FROM `123_options` WHERE `option_name` LIKE ('*transient*%')

Any pointers?

Comment: Use [`delete_transient()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/delete_transient/) function instead.

Comment: transients delete by themselves when they expire, do you have a reason to delete them? The issue is in your quotes, double quotes and backticks most likely

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? If this throws a database error, have you tried running the query manually? Would it work without the brackets around `'transient%'`?